# VsTest doesnt run with arguments generated by powershell

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, powershell, testing, jenkins-plugins

I have written a simple powershell script to generate all the list of test DLLs, using some help in stackover and other places.

```
{

    cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow"
    $sourceDirectory = "D:\workspace\SolutionDir"
    $files = get-childitem $sourceDirectory -recurse -include "*.Test*.dll" | select -expand FullName | where {$_ -like "*.Test*.dll"}
    foreach ($file in $files)
    {
        $cFiles = $cFiles + $file.trim() + " "
    }
    $cFiles = $cFiles -replace ".{}$" #drop last 1 chars

    echo $cFiles

    $argumentList = @("$cFiles", "/framework:framework45", "/platform:x64")

    vstest.console.exe $argumentList
}
```

But I get an error

> Error: The test source file "D:\workspace\SolutionDir\Proj1.Test\bin\x64\Release\Proj1.Test.dll D:\workspace\SolutionDir\Proj2.Test\bin\x64\Release\Proj2.Test.dll
>   D:\workspace\SolutionDir\Proj3.Test\bin\x64\Release\Proj3.Test.dll" was not found

When I echo the argument list, delete the spaces and type them manually and copy the command back into powershell, it works. I am suspecting that this has something to do with the encoding of the strings. But I am not able to figure out how to change it or otherwise make it work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but it may teach you how to answer your own question. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/09/20/solve-problems-with-external-command-lines-in-powershell/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is your vstest is expected to take each filename as an argument, but you are passing all files as 1. Instead, can you try this?

```
{

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow"
$sourceDirectory = "D:\workspace\SolutionDir"
$files = get-childitem $sourceDirectory -recurse -include "*.Test*.dll" | select -expand FullName | where {$_ -like "*.Test*.dll"}
$argumentList = @()

foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $argumentList += $file
}

$argumentList += "/framework:framework45"
$argumentList += "/platform:x64"

vstest.console.exe $argumentList
}
```

If this does not work for you, then you probly should not parse the result of get-childitem

Try this instread

```
{

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow"
$sourceDirectory = "D:\workspace\SolutionDir"
$files = get-childitem $sourceDirectory -recurse | where {$_ -like "*.Test*.dll"}
$argumentList = @()

foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $argumentList += $file.FullName
}

$argumentList += "/framework:framework45"
$argumentList += "/platform:x64"

vstest.console.exe $argumentList
}
```